# problem with facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have placed the facebook like button on  a website, and the weirdest thing is happening, every page on the site shows the same count for the number of people liking the site (~ 760), except the home page, the home page shows 18 people only.
for the life of me I cannot figure out what's causing this.
All pages are using the same open graph meta tags, and the facebook snippet is inserted by a user control (same on every page).
Anyone has any ideas where I can even start to debug?

The site is canvaspop.com

Comment: So are you trying to make everything different or everything the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.canvaspop.com/default.aspx&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&width=130&action=like&font=arial&colorscheme=light&height=21

Looking at the DOM and XHR Responses that data is coming directly from facebook without any problems.

to be perfectly honest, I would not rely too much on data coming from facebook, the amount load they have and there forever changing CDN, there's bound to be issues with the balance loader, that data as its the root of your domain may be coming from a cached result to decrease laod.

you can image the % of content delivered to homepage's rather then inner site pages, because users usually go on a site and then go off.

just wait it out and see if the results get updated. if it does not then go to the Developers Support areas and ask a member of the community or team!

Comment: as ive just posted this and rechecked the content now says 761, so as i say, there laod balancers probably serving a cached value!

Comment: you're absolutely right, as I was continuing to scratch my head, I checked the site again and it was returning the right count.

Comment: I had the same kind of issues when I was developing a C# Messenger application for a client, you cant really xomplain as the service your gettings is 1.Free 2.Simple 3. Beneficial for traffic, list is endless :)

Answer (score 1):

Install fiddler, and look at the request sent to facebook on the homepage vs the other pages.